# The request was missing an Authentification Key FCM Token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to hit using postman firebase url but it is giving me error. 
I have setup all the things but it still it is giving me error

Here is the error which I am getting on postman

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>The request was missing an Authentification Key (FCM Token). Please, refer to section &quot;Authentification&quot; of the FCM documentation, at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
        <H1>The request was missing an Authentification Key (FCM Token). Please, refer to section &quot;Authentification&quot; of the FCM documentation, at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.</H1>
        <H2>Error 401</H2>
    </BODY>
</HTML>


These things I am adding <br/>
url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'<br/>
method = POST<br/>
Headers <br/>
Authorization = 'FIREBASE_SERVER_API_KEY'<br/>
Content-Type = application/json<br/>
Body = 
"{"registration_ids":["ids"],"priority":"high\",\"data\":{\"notification_id\":76,\"title\":\"dvxcv\",\"description\":\"xcvxv\",\"image\":\"/uploads/image/image/37513/Screenshot_from_2016-10-17_10_43_59.png\"}}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do first in Header 
Authorization:  key='FIREBASE_SERVER_API_KEY'

And you are having problems with json parsing you have to remove '/'

```
{"registration_ids":["ids"],"priority":"high","data":{"notification_id":76,"title":"dvxcv","description":"xcvxv","image":"/uploads/image/image/37513/Screenshot_from_2016-10-17_10_43_59.png"}}
```

Edit
For any confusion follow my tutorial 
[how to integrate firebase with ruby on rails](https://railsbyaniket.blogspot.in/2016/12/integrate-firebase-with-ruby-on-rails.html)

Comment: I get the same message in Postman and I have the Authorization : key= (this is the FCM token showing in the Cloud messaging tab)

Comment: This is given in the docs and is not working, did anyone get a solution?

Comment: it is working correctly may i know where you have gone wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Under Headers, Authorization: key=AAAA.....

HAVE TO ADD "key=" in front of the Firebase Server key token!!!